# Finding the coordinate at time $t$ of a line determined by the points $(x1,y1), (x2,y2)$

Tags: geometry, parametric

I have the problem here, I create a program that clipping a line  with the input `(x1,y1,x2,y2)`. but the algorithm only explain until I get `tmin` and `tmax` (so the line would be (`tmin` - `tmax`)).

The only algorithm says is the `t` is from `0` `(x1,y1)` to `1` `(x2,y2)`

The problem is for the program, program has to show (draw) the line, of course that needs `(x, y)` coordinate.

How do I get the position `x` and `y` from given `t`?

I have Googled that stuff, but I still don't understand it.  :(

***Note:***

Seriously, I don't really understand about math, please go easy with the explanation. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant-speed parameterization $\gamma(t)$ of a line satisfying $$\gamma(0) = (x_1, y_1), \qquad \gamma(1) = (x_2, y_2)$$
is
$$\gamma(t) = (1 - t)(x_1, y_1) + t(x_2, y_2) = ((1 - t) x_1 + t x_2, (1 - t) y_1 + t y_2),$$
or if one prefers,
$$\color{#bf0000}{
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} x(t) &=& (1 - t) x_1 + t x_2 \\
                          y(t) &=& (1 - t) y_1 + t y_2\end{array}\right.}
$$

Comment: That's it, thanks...

now i can finish my program. :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!